# Regular $n$-gons and Linear Tranformations

Tags: linear-algebra, polygons

Let $P$ be a *regular* $n$-gon and let $Q$ be an another *convex* polygon with the same number of vertices. Is there always a *linear transformation* $M\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $M(P) = Q$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Linear transformations take pairs of parallel lines to pairs of parallel lines; a linear transformation of a square is always a parallelogram